# sqlite3_open databasePath

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

i'm new here asking questions, but i've been searching here for several issues. Thanks for your help.
Now I'm developing an app using sqlite, and when I uses this code line in AddViewController.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Tutorial.h"

.
.
.
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath NSUTF8StringEncoding], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
.
.
.
```

the program says: use of undeclared identifier 'databasePath:'
I've tryed several ways but it just says that 'databasePath' is not declared or not @interface. But 'database' is declared in the same way in the AppDelegate.h and is not giving the same error.

Here is where are declared: AppDelegate.h

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    NSString *databaseName;
    NSString *databasePath;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *databaseName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *databasePath;
```

I've been searching a lot to solve it but I haven't found how to declarate 'databasePath'

Hope you can help me.
Thanks

Comment: sorry. Is Objective-C, and i'm using Xcode 4.6 for iOS

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `databasePath` is an instance variable of `AppDelegate` and not of `AddViewController`.

Insert these lines before the sqlite3_open statement:

```
AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
NSString* databasePath = [appDelegate databasePath];
```

I'd also encourage you to use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb/), an Objective-C wrapper around SQLite.